# How to upgrade from Laravel 4.2 to 5?

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5

How do I upgrade from Laravel 4.2 to 5 dev?

Yes, I have read the documentation but it doesn't help. What I've done so far is updated the composer.json and then I ran composer update --no-scripts.

But the file structure seems to be the same...

Would it be easier to just do a fresh install and move files and code over manually?

Comment: Yes a fresh install is easier. Composer does only affect the files inside of the `vendor` directory

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll do that. Lucky its a new project... otherwise it would've been very time consuming.

Comment: For future readers, there's now an [automated upgrade tool for Laravel projects](https://laravelshift.com) named *Laravel Shift*. Definitely worth it for the 4.2 upgrade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5 is not even in Beta yet.

Once it is available for use - Taylor will provide a structured upgrade process to move from 4.2 to 5.

In the meantime, you should be careful about using Laravel 5 - as the structure is changing almost daily, so Taylor does not recommend using it in projects yet.

**Edit:** Laravel 5 has now officially been released. [Here is the official upgrade guide.](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade)